# Remove leading '0's from all strings in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, for-loop

### My code

```
l=['99','08','096']
for i in l:
    if i.startswith('0'):
        i.replace('0','')
print(l)
```

### Output

```
l=['99','08','096']
```

I just want to remove the leading '0's from all the strings:

```
l=['99','8','96']
```

Comment: In Python strings aren't mutable so `replace` returns a new string.

Comment: Do you want to remove those strings from the list completely (as your title says), or just remove the leading zeros (as it seems like your code is trying to do)? What is the expected output for your example?

Comment: what is your expected output? you want to remove the entire string or to strip 0?

Comment: I just want to remove the leading '0's from all the strings

Comment: expected output:- l=['99','8','96']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`str.lstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) for this in a list comprehension - to remove all leading `'0'`s from each string.

```
>>> l = ['99', '08', '096']
>>> [x.lstrip('0') for x in l]
['99', '8', '96']
```

This has the added benefit of not removing instances of `'0'` from within the string, only from the front.

```
>>> l=['99', '08', '096', '0102']
>>> [x.lstrip('0') for x in l]
['99', '8', '96', '102']
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want to remove the string from the array if it starts with 0, but from the code you showed, you are just replacing the 0 in the string with nothing. `i.replace('0','')`

one way to filter out is:

`new_list = [el for el in l if not el.startswith('0')]`

Answer (score 0):

you can use list comprehension to correct your strings by using str.lstrip:

```
[e.lstrip('0') for e in l]
```

or you can use a for loop:

```
for i in range(len(l)):
    if l[i].startswith('0'):
        l[i] = l[i][1:]
```